# Rake migration cannot find the table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rails-migrations

So I have created a manual file name 001_create_users.rb in db->migrate folder like this:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :password
      t.string :bio

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

Then I run a : `bundle exec rake db:migrate` command and I get this error:

> rake aborted! An error has occurred, this and all later migrations
>   canceled:
>
> Could not find table 'create_users'

The error is more details tho, so I just copy-paste it from terminal window, but the first part the head of the error I get

> rake aborted! An error has occurred, this and all later migrations
>   canceled:
>
> Could not find table 'create_users'
>   /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@railsbabak/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:472:in `table_structure'
>   /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@railsbabak/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:346:in`columns'
>   /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@railsbabak/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:12:in
>   `block in initialize'
>   /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@railsbabak/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in`
>   yield'
>   /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@railsbabak/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in
>   `default'
>   /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@railsbabak/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in`
>   columns'
>   /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@railsbabak/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:243:in
>   `column_defaults'
>   /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@railsbabak/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:482:in`
>   initialize'
>   /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@railsbabak/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:538:in
>   `new'
>   /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@railsbabak/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:538:in`
>   load_migration'
>   /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@railsbabak/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:533:in
>   `migration'
>   /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@railsbabak/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in`
>   migrate'
>   /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@railsbabak/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:720:in
>   `block (2 levels) in migrate'
>   /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@railsbabak/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in`
>   call'
>   /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@railsbabak/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in
>   `block in ddl_transaction'
>   /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@railsbabak/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in`
>   transaction'
>   /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@railsbabak/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in
>   `transaction'
>   /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@railsbabak/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in`
>   ddl_transaction'
>   /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@railsbabak/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:719:in
>   `block in migrate'
>   /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@railsbabak/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in`
>   each'
>   /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@railsbabak/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in
>   `migrate'
>   /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@railsbabak/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in`
>   up'
>   /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@railsbabak/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in
>   `migrate' /Users/JonyIve/Documents/HisFirstService/Rakefile:19:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@railsbabak/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in
>   `eval'
>   /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@railsbabak/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in`
>   ' Tasks: TOP => db:migrate (See full trace by running task with
>   --trace)

Also if I say "which gem" here is what I get:

```
which gem
/Users/JonyIve/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/gem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base` when it should be `ActiveRecord::Migration`.

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :projects do |t|
      t.text :title
      t.text :description
      t.text :slug

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```